# UILabel - issue with flexible size and fixed sapce

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uilabel

I'm trying to view information on 3 different lables;
First. Title
Two. Release date
Three. Description

Between the title and release date have two blank lines. Sometimes when the title gets more than 3 lines is written on the date of publication.
here is a picture (the bold line is the pub date label):
[image: title gets on pubDate]

**and sometimes when the description label get large amount of text thats what happend:**
[image]

**this is how its should be:**

[image]

so the questions:
 1. how can i save a fixed space between the title and the pubdate? (no matter how much lines the title is will remain between the two a fixed space)
 2. why the description move down when he gets a large amount of text? how can i fixed his place?

i just want to save a space between the 3 labels no matter how much lines each has.

here is my code so far:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{


    [super viewDidLoad];

    [_scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [_scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 600)];


    self.lblDescription.text = self.description;
    self.lblTitle.text = self.stitle;
    self.lblPubDate.text = self.pubDate;


    self.lblTitle.numberOfLines = 0;
    [self.lblTitle sizeToFit];
    self.lblTitle.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
    CGRect titleFram = self.lblTitle.frame;
    titleFram = CGRectMake(titleFram.origin.x, titleFram.origin.y, 280, titleFram.size.height);
    self.lblTitle.frame = titleFram;

    self.lblDescription.numberOfLines = 0;
    [self.lblDescription sizeToFit];

    [self resizeHeightToFitForLabel:self.lblTitle];
    [self resizeHeightToFitForLabel:self.lblDescription];


}
-(void)resizeHeightToFitForLabel:(UILabel *)label
{
    CGRect newFrame         = label.frame;
    newFrame.size.height    = [self heightForLabel:label withText:label.text];
    label.frame             = newFrame;
}

-(CGFloat)heightForLabel:(UILabel *)label withText:(NSString *)text
{
    CGSize maximumLabelSize     = CGSizeMake(290, FLT_MAX);

    CGSize expectedLabelSize    = [text sizeWithFont:label.font
                                   constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize
                                       lineBreakMode:label.lineBreakMode];

    return expectedLabelSize.height;
}
```

what is the best way to get this done?
thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [_scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [_scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 600)];

    //Use this way
    [self positionLabel:self.lblTitle withText:self.stitle withY:10];
    [self positionLabel:self.lblPubDate withText:self.pubDate withY:CGRectGetMaxY(self.lblTitle.frame)+10 ];
    [self positionLabel:self.lblDescription withText:self.description withY:CGRectGetMaxY(SELF.lblPubDate.frame)+10 ];

}

-(void)positionLabel:(UILabel*)lbl withText:(NSString*)text withY:(CGFloat)Y
{
    lbl.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
    lbl.text = text;
    lbl.numberOfLines = 0;
    lbl.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    CGSize size = [self calculateSize:lbl];
    //FIXED
    [lbl setFrame:CGRectMake(10 , Y , (size.width>310)?size.width:310 , size.height)]; 
}

-(CGSize)calculateSize:(UILabel*)lbl
{
    CGSize size = [lbl.text sizeWithFont:lbl.font
                       constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(310, MAXFLOAT)
                           lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    return size;
}
```

Comment: all the labels goes out of the view fram.. only when im scrolling i can see them..
the pubDate is not align to the right but everything looks fine..
how can i fix it?

Comment: I am not sure but try this [_scroller addSubview:lbl]; in positionLabel method.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28437/discussion-between-bhargavi-and-oshrialm)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way,

```
NSString *lbltext1 = lblTitle.text;
    NSString *lbltext2 = lblDate.text;
    NSString *lbltext3 = lblDesc.text;

CGRect rect = self.lblTitle.frame;
rect.size.height = [ViewController calculateHeightForText:lbltext1 font:self.lblTitle.font size:CGSizeMake(rect.size.width, 40000)].height;
self.lblTitle.frame = rect;

rect = self.lblDate.frame;
rect.origin.y = CGRectGetMaxY(self.lblTitle.frame) + 5;
rect.size.height = [ViewController calculateHeightForText:lbltext2 font:self.lblDate.font size:CGSizeMake(rect.size.width, 40000)].height;
self.lblDate.frame = rect;

rect = self.lblDesc.frame;
rect.origin.y = CGRectGetMaxY(self.lblDate.frame) + 5;
rect.size.height = [ViewController calculateHeightForText:lbltext3 font:self.lblDesc.font size:CGSizeMake(rect.size.width, 40000)].height;
self.lblDesc.frame = rect;
```

for caculate height,

```
+ (CGSize)calculateHeightForText:(NSString *)text font:(UIFont *)font size:(CGSize)size {
    CGSize _size = [text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:size lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    return _size;
}
```

Comment: this code fixed my 1st problem.. no matter how much lines the title is there is a space between the title and PudDate..
but the description still dont have a fixed place..

Comment: what are you doing for that?

Comment: do you have any suggestion?

Comment: have you check whitespace and newline tag? and try to solve this issue   with doing backGround color of label so you can identify what's going wrong...

Comment: i did this:
self.description = [_description stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

its fixed it..

Answer (score 0):

calculate its content height using my bellow custom method...

```
(float) calculateHeightOfTextFromWidth:(NSString*) text: (UIFont*)withFont: (float)width :(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode
{
[text retain];
[withFont retain];
CGSize suggestedSize = [text sizeWithFont:withFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, FLT_MAX) lineBreakMode:lineBreakMode];

[text release];
[withFont release];

return suggestedSize.height;
}
```

and use it like bellow..

```
UILabel *lblAddress = [[UILabel alloc]init];
[lblAddress setFrame:CGRectMake(110, 31, 200, 50)];        
lblAddress.text = @"your Text ";
lblAddress.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
lblAddress.numberOfLines = 0;
lblAddress.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];

lblAddress.frame = CGRectMake(lblAddress.frame.origin.x, lblAddress.frame.origin.y, 
                         200,[self calculateHeightOfTextFromWidth:lblAddress.text :lblAddress.font :200 :UILineBreakModeWordWrap] ); 

lblAddress.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

[self.view addSubview:lblAddress];
```

See [My Blog](http://parasjoshi3.blogspot.in/2012/11/set-uilabel-with-adjust-content-text.html)...

Comment: apply this custom method for each of my labels?

Comment: anything you want you can use it.. also here i just give you the example that how to use that method... you can maintain the frame of lable or textfield dynamically...

Comment: Sorry if I bother you but I'm a bit new and not so understand what to do, can you direct me a little more?
i would be greatful..

Comment: here in my method i just calculate the height with lenght of text and its font size and then set to the UILable or any control see...i call that method in this line lblAddress.frame = CGRectMake(lblAddress.frame.origin.x, lblAddress.frame.origin.y, 
                         200,[self calculateHeightOfTextFromWidth:lblAddress.text :lblAddress.font :200 :UILineBreakModeWordWrap] ); here this method return float value and then its assign to the UILable's height...

Comment: the label is really narrow.. how can i expand it?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 self.lblDescription.text = @"asdfasfadfsa";
    self.lblTitle.text = @"asdafsasf";
    self.lblPubDate.text = @"asdafsas";


    self.lblTitle.numberOfLines = 0;
    [self.lblTitle sizeToFit];
    self.lblTitle.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
    CGRect titleFram = self.lblTitle.frame;
    titleFram = CGRectMake(titleFram.origin.x, titleFram.origin.y, 280, titleFram.size.height);
    self.lblTitle.frame = titleFram;

    self.lblDescription.numberOfLines = 0;
    [self.lblDescription sizeToFit];

    [self resizeHeightToFitForLabel:self.lblTitle];

    CGRect pubFrame =self.lblPubDate.frame;
    pubFrame.origin.y= self.lblTitle.frame.origin.y+self.lblTitle.frame.size.height+110;

    [self.lblPubDate setFrame:pubFrame];

    CGRect descFrame =self.lblDescription.frame;
    descFrame.origin.y= self.lblPubDate.frame.origin.y+self.lblPubDate.frame.size.height+30;


    [self resizeHeightToFitForLabel:self.lblDescription];
```